# The element LinearLayout has an invalid child multiselectspinner.multiselectspinner

Tags: xamarin.android

Followed the guide from: 
https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/FileUpload/72/535f17b6e5737cdf0a12e105218ec7.txt

facing this issue in layout main.axml file that The element LinearLayout has an invalid child multiselectspinner.multiselectspinner.

My main.axml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <MultiSelectSpinnerExample.MultiSelectSpinner
        android:id="@+id/my_spin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in your on create method add a try catch and provide the stacktrace for the same

Comment: it gives the spinner object as null, i tried by debugging coz it is not picking the MultiSelectSpinner as a child in view.

Comment: Can i see your on create method?